# Adding Custom View With LinearLayout to ListView Programmatically Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I believe I'm having this issue because of a combination of lack of sleep and inexperience with android.

I have an app with two fragments. The fragment on the left(the one I'm concerned with) is declared like this:

```
public class CollageLibraryFragment extends ListFragment implements ListAdapter
```

I want it to hold a list of custom views that have a thumbnail of an image, some data about that image, and a button in a vertical LinearLayout.

I've been able to successfully show a list of just ImageViews, but my custom ViewGroup containing the image and a button(data will come once I get that to show up) doesn't appear in the list.

My guess is that I need to implement onDraw or onLayout in my custom ViewGroup, but I'm not sure what to do here and I've been messing around for 4+ hours embarrassingly.

Here is some relevant code:

In CollageLibraryFragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _pictureCollageDataModel = PictureCollageDataModel.getInstance();
    _images = _pictureCollageDataModel.getCollageImages();
    if(_listView == null)
        _listView = new ListView(getActivity());

    _listView.setAdapter(this);
}
....
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ThumbnailView thumbnailView = new ThumbnailView(getActivity(), _images.get(i));
    //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    //imageView.setImageBitmap(_images.get(i)._image.getBitMap());
    return thumbnailView;
}
....
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //link to list view
    return _listView;
}
```

Notice the commented out ImageView in the getView method. That does show up in my list fragment as expected. However, when I switch to ThumbnailView it does not show up.

My entire Thumbnail view:

```
public class ThumbnailView extends ViewGroup
{
    Bitmap _thumbnail;
    LinearLayout _mainViewGroup = null;
    public ThumbnailView(Context context, CollageImage image)
    {
        super(context);
        _thumbnail = image._image.getBitMap();
        _mainViewGroup = new LinearLayout(context);
        _mainViewGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        _mainViewGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ImageView thumbView = new ImageView(context);
        thumbView.setImageBitmap(_thumbnail);

        _mainViewGroup.addView(thumbView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        Button addButton = new Button(context);
        addButton.setText("+");
        _mainViewGroup.addView(addButton);
        this.addView(_mainViewGroup);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        _mainViewGroup.setMinimumWidth(100);
        _mainViewGroup.setMinimumHeight(100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

    }
}
```

Right now I feel like I'm just looking at this blankly, and I'm sure I'm just not defining things properly or putting them in the right methods, but I've just hit a wall for some reason and I just need a little nudge in the right direction I think so I can continue.

Any help will be extremely glorious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't too difficult actually. I changed from extending ViewGroup to extending LinearLayout, got rid of my onLayout method and just added views. Here is what I ended up with for my ThumbnailView.

```
public class ThumbnailView extends LinearLayout
{
    Bitmap _thumbnail;
    //LinearLayout _mainViewGroup = null;
    public ThumbnailView(Context context, CollageImage image)
    {
        super(context);
        _thumbnail = image._image.getBitMap();

        ImageView thumbView = new ImageView(context);
        thumbView.setImageBitmap(_thumbnail);

        Button addButton = new Button(context);
        addButton.setText("+");

        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        this.addView(thumbView);
        this.addView(addButton);
    }
}
```